# REST module get/set cookie(s)

Tags: codeception

I'm writing some tests with the codeception REST module.

The project I'm working on is in the early stages and we haven't implemented token-based authentication yet; so for now the authentication is done via a REST API but it uses `$_SESSION` for persistence.

To test authenticated requests I need to keep the `PHPSESSID` cookie and send it with every request. Is there a way to read/set cookies when working with the REST module?

Comment: The client will reset the cookie if you send a new one with each response.  I'm not sure I understand what your problem is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I got the solution. My suite name is `api`, so codeception generated a file at `tests/_support/Helper/Api.php`. Before making changes here, I had to edit my suite YAML file `api.suite.yml` to enable the helper. My YAML file looks like this:

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - REST:
            depends: PhpBrowser
            url: https://website.com/api/
            part: Json
        - \Helper\Api
```

Now that the file is enabled, run `codecept build` so that it updates the generated files to read your helper.

In the `Api` helper class, I added two methods:

```
public function capturePHPSESSID()
{
  $cookie = $this->getClient()->getCookieJar()->get('PHPSESSID');
  echo "Cookie: ", $cookie;
}

/**
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client|\Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client $client
 */
protected function getClient()
{
  return $this->getModule('REST')->client;
}
```

This is all that you need to read the PHPSESSID cookie! Feel free to capture it so you can then write a method to re-use it by setting calling `$this->getClient()->getCookieJar()->set(....)`